# How to trigger validation of a particular field manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The section below is working fine. In certain condition one field is made readonly and in that condition I have to validate the field.

How to trigger a validation on a particular field manually??

```js
$('#myForm').formValidation({
  framework: 'bootstrap',
  err: {
    container: function($field, validator) {
      return $field.parent().parent().next('.messageContainer');
    }
  },
  icon: {
    valid: 'fa ',
    invalid: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
    validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
  },
  fields: {
    'RC_BEAM_DESIGN_BS8110_V1_Model.Breadth_b': {
      err: 'popover',
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'Breadth must have value'
        },
        numeric: {
          message: 'Breadth must be Number'
        },
        between: {
          message: 'Breadth Range should be between 50 - 2500 ',
          min: 50,
          max: 2500
        }
      }
    },
    'RC_BEAM_DESIGN_BS8110_V1_Model.Depth_h': {
      err: 'popover',
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'Depth must have value'
        },
        numeric: {
          message: 'Depth must be Number'
        },
        between: {
          message: 'Depth Range should be between 50 - 2500 ',
          min: 50,
          max: 2500
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I formatted your code and retagged it. Please add/remove tags that are relevant, mvc is not a relevant tag for a jQuery question

Comment: @mplungjan, mistagged.   `.formValidation()` is not a part of the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: OP, please edit your question to explain exactly which jQuery plugin you’re using for form validation.